# Using Audacity to generate power spectral density

Tags: acoustics, data-analysis

Say I record something with a sound recording program like Audacity (e.g. plucking a guitar string). How could I use that recording to plot a dB vs Frequency graph?

Comment: @alemi: You did this for the coin dropping experiment and I am interested to know how you used the software in this way.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question about software, not physics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By going to the *Analyze* Menu and selecting *Plot Spectrum*:
[image: Plot Spectrum in Menu]

You can generate the power spectral density with different windowing functions and settings:
[image: Power Spectral Density]

As well as export it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old thread, but just in case someone finds it googling around...

The real answer is that, unfortunately, you can't. What Audacity plots is not the power spectral density (PSD), but the power spectrum (PS). Regardless of the fact that you may be happy with it, the two are not the same thing.

The PS represents the power in each frequency bin, and as such for a broadband signal is dependent on the width of the bins used (the larger a bin, the more power falls into it). The PSD is the power per unit frequency, and for a broadband signal is basically independent on the bin size (except that if you use larger bins, you will calculate a PSD which is averaged over the width of the bin).

Try this in Audacity: create two tracks. In one generate white noise, in the other a tone at a frequency f0 of your choice. Now select both and go to "frequency analysis". You should see a relatively flat "background" with a peak at f0. If now you change the "size" (which is the size of the temporal window used, and thus determines the width of the bins), your background will change, while your peak remains almost unchanged (this actually doesn't work as well as it should, and I believe it is due to some interpolation that Audacity is performing on the graphical representation of the spectrum. It get close however for non-extreme value of "size"). This is because the power associated with your tone is constant, while the total power that the noise dumps in each bin decreases with the size of the bin. If you were to plot the PSD instead, the level of the noise will remain unchanged, while the peak will increase as you reduce the size of the bins. This is because the power associated with the tone is really only at frequency f0 (or a very narrow band around it), but if you calculate the density over a much larger bin, you see it "distributed" over a larger band, decreasing the average density. As the bin becomes smaller and smaller, you see the the tone power distributed over a smaller and smaller frequency band, thus increasing its density.

This said, the PSD is obtained dividing the PS by the width of the bin. So you can calculate the PS with Audacity, export it and divide it by the bin width. However, you if have to leave Audacity anyway, you may be better off calculating your PSD outside anyway (there are plenty of libraries to do it with many different scientific programming languages).

Comment: The intervals in discrete Fourier analysis are not bins in the sense that a histogram has bins.  I understand that the terminology has become standard, but it is misleading.The domain of frequencies in the DFT is a set of discrete points.

Comment: Interesting point, and one I have not admittedly fully though through. However, in the (ideal) physical process "continuos monochromatic signal -> limited time observation -> sampling -> DFT" it is true that (original) frequencies that do not exactly correspond to the ones represented in the DFT will not get lost, but will contribute to one (or more) of the DFT points. So, at least in this "physical" sense, it seems to me that DFT points can be called "bins" since they collect contributions by nearby frequencies...

Comment: The difficulty is that nearby frequencies do not appear nearby.  A periodic signal whose period is commensurate with the sample time will produce amplitude at one frequency point.   If the frequency is not commensurate but nearby to a commensurate frequency, amplitude appears over a large range of frequencies.  It does not appear at the nearby commensurate frequency as if binned.  I've heard the phrase "energy is spread all over the spectrum".   Technically correct, but not a practically useful phrase.  Windowing should be used, and interpretation takes skill.  But bins ... they are not.